# The proof of the countability of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let a function $f: A \rightarrow R $ be defined on $A$ and have a local extremum at each non-isolated point of this set. How to prove that the set $ f (A)$ is either finite or countable?

Comment: I think you're going to need to tell us more about your function and the sets involved..

Comment: Find an injection from $f(A)$ into $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1):

The result is true for any function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R.$ To see this, fix $n\in \mathbb N.$ Then let $A_n=\{x\in \mathbb R: |x-y|<1/n \Rightarrow f(y)<f(x)\}.$ Now, let $k\in \mathbb N$ and define $I_{nk}:=\left [\frac{k}{2n},\frac{k+1}{2n}\right ].$ Then, $I_{nk}\cap A_n$ is either empty or a singleton. Hence, $A_n=\bigcup_kI_{nk}\cap A_n$ is countable, and therefore so is $A=\bigcup_n A_n.$ To finish, note that $A$ is precisely the set of all local maxima for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a hint. I assume that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

**Fact.**
*Suppose that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Every function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can have at most countably many local extrema.*

Indeed, for every local maximum $a$ pick an open interval $U_a$ with both endpoints being rational numbers such that $a\in U_a$ and $f(a) > f(x)$ for $x\in U_a\setminus \{a\}$. This gives an injection

$$\big\{\mbox{ local maxima }\big\}\rightarrow \big\{\mbox{ open intervals of }\mathbb{R}\mbox{ with both endpoints rational}\big\}$$

This shows that the set of local maxima is at most countable. We deal similarly with local minima.

**Remark.** The result holds, if we replace $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ by any second countable topological space $X$.

In general using the fact you can prove that if there exists a function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on a second countable space $X$ such that each nonisolated point of $X$ is a local extremum of $f$, then $X$ is at most countable (and hence $f(X)$ is at most countable too).

Comment: A is not countable We associate each point of the line with open intervals with both endpoints rational . It does not follow from this that the line is countable.

Comment: @MorrisonFJ but in the case of extrema the correspondence above is injective. Let $A$ be the set of local maxima. Map $a \mapsto U_a$ is injective, because (by definition) $a$ is **the global maximum** of $f$ on $U_a$. Thus $U_{a_1} = U_{a_2}$ implies $a_1 = a_2$. (BTW. I should consider cases of local maxima and minima separately in the answer above)

Comment: from the coincidences U, the coincidence of the values of the functions at the points of the extrema will follow, not the coincidence of the extrema

Comment: @MorrisonFJ if extremum say local maximum of $f$ is such a point $a$ that there exists an open interval $U$ containing $a$ such that $f(x)<f(a)$ for all $x\in U\setminus \{a\}$, then you will have coincidence of arguments not values. if you change $<$ to $\leq$, then you will have equality of values. The definition is up to you.